# C++ template function for method with a parameter of a const type or simply of type

Tags: c++, templates, traits, template-argument-deduction

Assuming I have the same body for two template functions for calling class methods, like these:

```
 template <typename jsType, typename jsParamType, typename ParamPrivateType = jsParamType::PrivateType, void(PrivateType::*Method)(const ParamPrivateType&)>
    static bool SetByRefMethod(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
{
...
}

 template <typename jsType, typename jsParamType, typename ParamPrivateType = jsParamType::PrivateType, void(PrivateType::*Method)(      ParamPrivateType&)>
    static bool SetByRefMethod(JSContext *cx, unsigned argc, JS::Value *vp)
{
...
}
```

I try to write once the body, so what is the right way to make the compiler to use it when the called method has a parameter `const` and when it has a parameter **not** `const`?

Comment: You could take the function pointer as a template `typename Func`. As an aside, your templates are all weird looking.

Comment: This is just a case, I have some other function types to call. I am bound to some third party APIs I can't touch so I need to use templates for parameterization.

Comment: This doesn't even look like it will compile to me. Non-defaulted template parameters cannot follow a defaulted template parameter.

Comment: They compile. But it is redundant to have the body twice...

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This is a bit tricky, but they can, and the reason is because there is an additional type deduction that may take place, in which some defaulted parameters may not enter. Example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24c16c2449d19d1f).

Comment: Would this call functions of type ReturnPrivateType(*PrivateType::*Method)(ParamPrivateType*) too? This would be not desirable in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution, but, is there a better way?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <type_traits>

class A {
public:
    using ClassType = int;

    void print_const_integer(const int& a) {
        cout << "A's member function accepting a const ref called" << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    void print_integer(int& a) {
        cout << "A's member function accepting a ref called" << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }

};
class B {
public:
    using ClassType = int;

    void print_integer(int& a) {
        cout << "B's member function called" << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }
};

template <typename TYPE, void(TYPE::*member_func_pointer)(int&)>
void function(TYPE object) {
    typename TYPE::ClassType a = 1;
    (object.*member_func_pointer)(a);
}

template <typename TYPE, void(TYPE::*member_func_pointer)(const int&)>
void function(TYPE object) {
    typename TYPE::ClassType a = 1;
    (object.*member_func_pointer)(a);
}


template <typename TYPE, typename FUNCTYPE>
 struct opt_const_param : std::enable_if<std::is_same<FUNCTYPE, void(TYPE::*)(      int&)>::value
                                      || std::is_same<FUNCTYPE, void(TYPE::*)(const int&)>::value, FUNCTYPE>
{
};

template <typename TYPE, typename FUNCTYPE, typename opt_const_param<TYPE, FUNCTYPE>::type member_func_pointer>
void function2(TYPE object) {
    typename TYPE::ClassType a = 1;
    (object.*member_func_pointer)(a);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    function2<A, void(A::*)(const int&), &A::print_const_integer>(a);
    function2<A, void(A::*)(int&), &A::print_integer>(a);
    function2<B, void(B::*)(int&), &B::print_integer>(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to template all those types.  Only the first will do.  If you can deduce the rest of the types using the first templated type you should be fine. You don't need the private types in the template if they can be deduced from the first template type.  Check out the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

class A {
public:
    using ClassType = int;

    void print_const_integer(const int& a) {
        cout << "A's member function accepting a const ref called" << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    void print_integer(int& a) {
        cout << "A's member function accepting a ref called" << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }

};
class B {
public:
    using ClassType = int;

    void print_integer(int& a) {
        cout << "B's member function called" << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }
};

template <typename TYPE>
void function(TYPE object, void (TYPE::*member_func_pointer)(int&)) {
    typename TYPE::ClassType a = 1;
    (object.*member_func_pointer)(a);
}

template <typename TYPE>
void function(TYPE object, void (TYPE::*member_func_pointer)(const int&)) {
    typename TYPE::ClassType a = 1;
    (object.*member_func_pointer)(a);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    function(a, &A::print_const_integer);
    function(a, &A::print_integer);
    function(b, &B::print_integer);

    return 0;
}
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: This is what I already have now. Except instead of `(object.*member_func_pointer)(a);` I have a big body, as in your example, twice. So, I hope I could use some `std::enable_if`, `std::is_same`and related stuff to reduce the two functions called in your example `function` to one.

Answer (score 0):

I have another approach here, it looks better for using with macros:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
#include <type_traits>

class A {
public:
    using ClassType = int;

    void print_const_integer(const int& a) {
        cout << "A's member function accepting a const ref called" << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }

    void print_integer(int& a) {
        cout << "A's member function accepting a ref called" << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }

};
class B {
public:
    using ClassType = int;

    void print_integer(int& a) {
        cout << "B's member function called" << endl;
        cout << a << endl;
    }
};

template <typename TYPE, typename FUNCTYPE>
 struct opt_const_param_function3 : std::enable_if<std::is_same<FUNCTYPE, void(TYPE::*)(      int&)>::value
                                      || std::is_same<FUNCTYPE, void(TYPE::*)(const int&)>::value, FUNCTYPE>
{
};

template <typename TYPE, typename FUNCTYPE, typename opt_const_param_function3<TYPE, FUNCTYPE>::type member_func_pointer> //FUNCTYPE member_func_pointer>
void function3(TYPE object) {
    typename TYPE::ClassType a = 1;
    (object.*member_func_pointer)(a);
}

template <typename TYPE, void(TYPE::*member_func_pointer)(int&)>
void function3(TYPE object) {
    function3<TYPE, decltype(member_func_pointer), member_func_pointer>(object);
}

template <typename TYPE, void(TYPE::*member_func_pointer)(const int&)>
void function3(TYPE object) {
    function3<TYPE, decltype(member_func_pointer), member_func_pointer>(object);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    function3<A, &A::print_const_integer>(a);
    function3<A, &A::print_integer>(a);
    function3<B, &B::print_integer>(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Any thoughts?